# modify items in a Generic List

Tags: c#, list, generics

i cannot modify generic List with :

```
var x = (PaypalResponse)Session["PaypalResponse"]; // x.Response is my List

x.Response.ToList().Where(i => i.Id== 1).ForEach(s => s.Selected = true);
```

where am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: If `x` is the list than why are you calling `x.Response`, after that why are you `.toList`ing it? That makes a new list.

Comment: What's the element type here? If it's a reference type, I'd expect this to work - although I wouldn't personally use `ForEach` like this.

Comment: var x = (PaypalResponse)Session["PaypalResponse"];
x.Response // Response is my List

Comment: I need to modify some of the fields in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
x.Response.Where(i => i.Id == 1).ToList().ForEach(s => s.Selected = true);
```

However, it's a bit of a waste of resources to construct a new list just for this one line of code. I'd recommend this instead:

```
foreach(var s in x.Response.Where(i => i.Id == 1))
{
    s.Selected = true;
}
```

If you only want to update at most one item, you can do this instead:

```
var s = x.Response.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1);
if (s != null)
{
    s.Selected = true;
}
```

And of course, if you *know* there will be one item to update, it's even easier:

```
x.Response.First(i => i.Id == 1).Selected = true;
```